# ADA Compliant Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, accessibility, screen-readers

Anyone making ADA (Americans with Disabilities Act) compliant Crystal reports?

Any documentation on best practices or tips and tricks?

So far, we're adding text objects in small fonts with white forecolors for the screenreaders and having problems finding an easy way to reset the taborder of the controls.

[This is all I've found so far](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/20326525-891e-2b10-eeaf-b6d7cf91cc82?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true)